# Access a UNC Path (Windows 8.1) Using a Microsoft Account on the Remote Computer (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, login, microsoft-account, unc

I feel that this should have a really straight forward answer but it is not coming to me and Google is not being much help so sorry for the noddy question.

If you have a share on a Windows 8.1 computer which is shared so just a Microsoft account user can access it, how do you access it from another (Windows 7) computer that does not have the Microsoft account?

The computers' domains are not the same and it is not the same as the email domain of the Microsoft account, so I cannot just use email@addressdomain.com as the username as this would equate to TargetComputerDomain\email@addressdomain.com and understandably this rather confuses things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MicrosoftAccount\email@addressdomain.com` as username and enter your password.